# How can you pipe a readable stream to gulp.dest()?

Tags: node.js, gulp

I've got the following sample code which attempts to pipe a stream to gulp.dest():

```
  var gulp = require('gulp');
  var stream = require('stream');

  var readable = new stream.Readable;
  readable.push('Hello, world!');
  readable.push(null);
  readable
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./test.txt'));
```

This code produces the following error:

```
path.js:146
      throw new TypeError('Arguments to path.resolve must be strings');
      ^
TypeError: Arguments to path.resolve must be strings
    at Object.win32.resolve (path.js:146:13)
    at DestroyableTransform.saveFile [as _transform] (C:\paylocity\expense\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\lib\dest\index.js:36:26)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (C:\paylocity\expense\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:184:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._write (C:\paylocity\expense\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:172:12)
    at doWrite (C:\paylocity\expense\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:237:10)
    at writeOrBuffer (C:\paylocity\expense\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:227:5)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write (C:\paylocity\expense\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:194:11)
    at Readable.ondata (_stream_readable.js:540:20)
    at Readable.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:373:10)
```

I can't, however, see what exactly is wrong with the code.  If I replace gulp.dest() with process.stdout then it works and the gulp.dest() works within the context of other calls.  What is a viable way of doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gulp works with Vinyl streams:

```
var gulp   = require('gulp'),
    stream = require('stream'),
    source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

var readable = new stream.Readable;
readable.push('Hello, world!');
readable.push(null);

readable
    .pipe(source('test.txt'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
```

A Gulp stream normally [begins with some file or files as source](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md), so you need to wrap that readable stream into a [Vinyl stream](https://github.com/hughsk/vinyl-source-stream) allowing Gulp and any gulp-plugin getting info from it like filename (obviously faked), avoiding that error of yours.

So, Gulp streams are streams of files, just [check the source](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/657213a52d5e9c19b85df6a42f76341a98c08ae8/package.json#L40)...

Comment: I'd be interested in hearing a bit of explanation concerning why you have to use vinyl, but your answer definitely provided me with a viable way forward.

Comment: @AlexMills, dunno, the main idea behind every stream is the same but you can stream from files like this to text, bytes and so on.

Comment: well, I can say also, much to my chagrin, that the streaming API in the fs node.js core module is different than Gulp's as well. really frustrating stuff.